# Conecptional issues designing a shopping cart for multilple user

Tags: java, arraylist, shopping-cart

For my assignment I have to create at least two classes. "ShoppingCart" and "Article". The programm shall be used by mutltiple user and should be able to add, remove and change items for the active user who is currently shopping.
Additionally I wanted to have the function to add or remove user, this means delete his shopping cart.

I already created both classes with basic get/set methods. I work primary in the ShoppingCart class to generate a new ShoppingCart for each user by using Hashmap key as user name and add an arraylist (article) to the map key (user). Before I continue shopping the systems ask me for the active user to assign the items correctly.

I faced several issues using hasmap, like I cannot access all Article details e.g. price for a specific key (user) or in general I'm not able to access the shopping cart Items of an user who was active before.

Therefore I wanted to know if there is another way to get this assigment done or if I'm doing basic mistakes because I'm a newbee.

Here is my current coding I have:

**Main Class**

```
public class Main {

    private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {        

        int amount;
        String customerName = "";       
        System.out.println("How many people wanna shop");
        amount = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
            System.out.println("User name:");
            customerName = sc.nextLine();
            new Warenkorb().initialCreation(customerName);          
        }       
    }
```

**Article Class**

```
class Artikel {
    private String itemName;
    private int itemPrice;
    private int itemTax;

    public Artikel(String itemName, int itemPrice, int itemTax) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
        this.itemTax = itemTax;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
            return itemName;
    }

    public int getItemPrice() {
        return itemPrice;
    }

    public int getItemTax() {
        return itemTax;
    }

    public void setItemPrice(int itemPrice) {
        this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
    }

    public void setItemQuantity(int itemTax) {
        this.itemTax = itemTax;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }
}
```

**Shopping Cart**

I didn't copied other methods here, because I'm not able to print all shopping carts incl. article details. It's even print the last shopping cart (user).

```
class Warenkorb {
private String customerName;
private ArrayList<Artikel> shoppingCart = new ArrayList<>();
private Map<String, ArrayList<Artikel>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Artikel>>();
private Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public  void initialCreation(String customerName) {
    String currentUser = customerName;
    int amountofitem;
    System.out.println("How many Arcticle do you want to create");
    amountofitem = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

    for (int i = 0; i < amountofitem; i++) {
        String artikelName = "";
        int price, qty;
        System.out.println(">>>Add Article<<<");
        System.out.println("Please enter article name");
        artikelName = sc.nextLine().trim().toString();
        System.out.println("Please enter price");
        price = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Please enter how many you would like to add -> quantity");
        qty = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        Artikel newArticle = new Artikel(artikelName, qty, price);
        shoppingCart.add(newArticle);
    }
    map.put(currentUser, shoppingCart);

    for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Artikel>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Shopping Cart of  " + entry.getKey());

        for (Artikel item : entry.getValue()) {
            System.out.println("Artikel" + " " + item.getItemName() + " " + item.getItemPrice() + "€ " + item.getItemTax() + "%.");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any hints/advices.

Comment: Where are you storing all the instances of WarenKorb for you to search later?

Comment: I thought I will do it in the Hasmap or is this not happening? It's my first java program sorry for that